# nsarray from plist can't return key values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist

I am using the following code to iterate through a plist to find a string 
i then want to use the values for the keys - fraction and number
unfortunately something isn't working and i can't figure it out

any help will be appreciated

```
    NSString *theNumber = @"0.0075";

    BOOL found = NO;
    NSUInteger f;
    for (f = 0; f < [selectorKeysFractions count]; f++) {
        NSString * stringFromArray = [selectorKeysFractions objectAtIndex:f];
        if ([theNumber isEqualToString:stringFromArray]) {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( found ) {

        // do found
        //this line fails with unrecognised selector message          
        NSLog(@"%@",[[selectorKeysFractions objectAtIndex:f]objectForKey:@"fraction"]);

    } else {
        // do not found

    }
```

my plist data looks like this

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>fraction</key>
<string>1/128</string>
<key>number</key>
<string>23.78</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>fraction</key>
<string>1/234</string>
<key>number</key>
<string>25</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i am setting up the array like this

```
 NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fractions" ofType:@"plist"];
 pickerData2 =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path2];
 selectorKeysFractions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[pickerData2 allKeys]];
```

i am doing something wrong but can't figure it out
please help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the message "objectForKey" to an object of NSString. You have to request your NSDictionary to get the right entry.

Check this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[pickerData2 objectForKey:[selectorKeysFractions objectAtIndex:f]]);
```

This should return your string.

Comment: Hi matzino  thanks for your answer. i must have some kind of programmers block or something as I've been messing with this for ages - appreciate your help :-)